# How to call the Intent from a class in service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a service. In the service, I will call a function in class. The function allows opening an Intent
My service is

```
public class service extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {       
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And my class is

```
public class classIntent extends Application{
    public void homeIntent()
    {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

In the service, I will call `homeIntent()` function as follows steps:

In the onCreate() of the service, I will use

```
private classIntent cIntent;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
cIntent=new classIntent();
...}
```

Then in the `onStartCommand()` function, I used

```
cIntent.homeIntent();
```

However, I got the error such as:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

How can I solve it? Do I right when my class `classIntent` extended from Application? I want to use some functions in the class such as: `getApplicationContext()`...If not correct, which class do I need to extend? I am running the app in the background. Thank all

My manifest is

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
       <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".service" />
    <activity android:enabled="true" android:name=".classIntent" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You really not need to do this way**, and it is very wrong.

Your class name code-style is not good, should be ClassName

`<activity android:enabled="true" android:name=".classIntent" />` `classIntent` is not a Activity in you code.

## you just need to:

use `getApplication().startActivity()` to do the work, `getApplication()` is a function `Service`, `Activity` has, if you only need the Application context, not some activities.

If you need to make code clear, I suggest a static `makeIntent` function you can put in your helper class or the class associate with the intent.

the code in Service only need call `getApplication().startActivity(XXX.makeIntent())`

Comment: Thank Gohan. So, my class name does not extend from any class. Is it right? Just use `public class classInten{}`

Comment: you don't need the `classInten`. just a static method startXXXActivity(context) will do the work.

Comment: I used the class to make my code more clear. Because all functions put in one service will make the code in the service too long. Hence, I separate the calling intent into another class as classIntent()

Comment: If I put the calling intent in the service, it worked well, but it makes the code in the service too long

Comment: I did not do it before. Could you give me some example class ? And let use my Intent in my above question